# How to portably convert a string into an uncommon integer type?

Tags: c, string, integer, c99, scanf

Some background: If I wanted to use for, for instance, `scanf()` to convert a string into a standard integer type, like `uint16_t`, I’d use `SCNu16` from `<inttypes.h>`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
uint16_t x;
char *xs = "17";
sscanf(xs, "%" SCNu16, &x);
```

But a more uncommon integer type like `pid_t` does not have any such thing; only the normal integer types are supported by `<inttypes.h>`.  To convert the other way, to portably `printf()` a `pid_t`, I can cast it to `intmax_t` and use `PRIdMAX`, like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
pid_t x = 17;
printf("%" PRIdMAX, (intmax_t)x);
```

However, there does not seem to be a way to portably `scanf()` into a `pid_t`.  So this is my question: How to do this portably?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
pid_t x;
char *xs = 17;
sscanf(xs, "%u", &x);  /* Not portable! pid_t might not be int! /*
```

I thought of `scanf()`ing to an `intmax_t` and then checking that the value is within `pid_t`’s limits before casting to `pid_t`, but there does not seem to be a way to get the maximum or minimum values for `pid_t`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is one robust and portable solution, which is to use `strtoimax()` and check for overflows.

That is, I parse an `intmax_t`, check for an error from `strtoimax()`, and then also see if it "fits" in a `pid_t` by casting it and comparing it to the original `intmax_t` value.

```
#include <inttypes.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iso646.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
char *xs = "17";            /* The string to convert */
intmax_t xmax;
char *tmp;
pid_t x;                    /* Target variable */

errno = 0;
xmax = strtoimax(xs, &tmp, 10);
if(errno != 0 or tmp == xs or *tmp != '\0'
   or xmax != (pid_t)xmax){
  fprintf(stderr, "Bad PID!\n");
} else {
  x = (pid_t)xmax;
  ...
}
```

It is not possible to use `scanf()`, because, (as I said in a comment) **`scanf()` will not detect overflows**.  But I was wrong in saying that none of the `strtoll()`-related functions takes an `intmax_t`; `strtoimax()` does!

It also will not work to use anything else than `strtoimax()` unless you know the size of your integer type (`pid_t`, in this case).

Answer (score 3):

It depends on exactly how portable you want to be.  POSIX says that `pid_t` is a signed integer type used to store process IDs and process group IDs.  In practice, you could assume with safety that `long` is big enough.  Failing that, your `intmax_t` must be big enough (so it will accept any valid `pid_t`); the trouble is, that type could accept values that are not legitimate in `pid_t`.  You're stuck between a rock and a hard place.

I would use `long` and not worry very much about it except for an obscure comment somewhere that a software archaeologist of 100 years hence will find and observe gives a reason why the 256-bit CPU is creaking to a halt when handed a 512-bit value as a `pid_t`.

[POSIX 1003.1-2008](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) is now available on the web (all 3872 pages of it, in PDF and HTML).  You have to register (free).  I got to it from the [Open Group Bookstore](http://www.opengroup.org/bookstore/catalog/c082.htm).

All that I see there is that it must be a signed integer type.  Clearly, all valid signed integer values fit into `intmax_t`.  I cannot find any information in `<inttypes.h>` or `<unistd.h>` that indicates PID_T_MAX or PID_T_MIN or other such values (but I've only just this evening got access to it, so it could be hidden where I haven't looked for it).  OTOH, I stand by my original comment - I believe that 32-bit values are pragmatically adequate, and I would use `long` anyway, which would be 64-bit on 8-bit machines.  I suppose that roughly the worst thing that could happen is that an 'appropriately privileged' process read a value that was too large, and sent a signal to the wrong process because of a mismatch of types.  I'm not convinced I'd be worried about that.

...oooh!...p400 under `<sys/types.h>`

> The implementation shall support one or more programming environments in which the widths
>   of blksize_t, pid_t, size_t, ssize_t, and suseconds_t are no greater than the width of type long.

Comment: I heard that the next POSIX standard would only require it to fit into an intmax_t, so using long is out.

What I actually did was depend on the GNU C library's docs saying pid_t would always be int, and commenting it.  The code uses other glibc-specific stuff anyway, so this is not a real problem.

Comment: I’ve already GOT a "pragmatically adequate" solution, by using a non-portable assumption (in code that was never portable in the first place).  What I WANTED was a truly portable solution, if such a thing actually exists.

Answer (score 0):

If you are really concerned you can `_assert(sizeof(pid_t) <= long)` or whatever type you choose for your '%' stuff.

As explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437802/how-to-portably-convert-a-string-into-an-uncommon-integer-type/437814#437814), the spec says `signed int`. If 'int' changes, your '%u' by definition changes with it.

Comment: sizeof does not actually concern itself with the possible values of a type, only the storage requirements in bytes.  So your code does not actually guarantee what you think it does.

Also, the spec says "signed integer type", not "signed int".  Big difference.