# Where is the list of the POSIX C API functions?

Tags: c, posix

I'm trying to find out where I can find documentation on POSIX functions, but coming up short. Any recommendations?

Comment: Do be careful to check which version of POSIX you're allowed to code to.  2008 - which I gave the refs to - is quite new and not all functions are necessarily available everywhere.  You might decide to write covers for some new functions, but you won't be able to that for some so don't use them.

Answer (score 23):

[POSIX 1003.1-2008](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm) is now available on the web (all 3872 pages of it, in PDF and HTML). You have to register (free). I got to it from the [Open Group Bookstore](http://www.opengroup.org/bookstore/catalog/c082.htm).

See [How to Portably scanf into a pid_t in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437802/how-to-portably-scanf-into-a-pidt-in-c#437814) for my original answer that included this information.

Comment: Registration is not needed anymore for HTML. Can you provide a link to the PDF?

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功: I don't now remember where I thought the PDF could be obtained from — or whether it was free.  However, if you follow the link to the Open Group Bookstore above, and then chase links (because the 2008 edition is no longer available), you can find https://www2.opengroup.org/ogsys/jsp/publications/PublicationDetails.jsp?publicationid=14670.  You could also find http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/974398/versions using a Google search term 'posix.1-2016 pdf'.  You'll need to assess whether they're useful to you, and acceptably priced.

Comment: Thanks. I knew a bout the paid PDFs, just curious if there were free PDFs too. I'll keep using `wget`-fu in the meanwhile: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45832939/895245

Comment: @CiroSantilli刘晓波死六四事件法轮功: There are complete compressed HTML downloads available from the download link on pages such as the http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/toc.htm page.  That may save you some fetches.

Answer (score 5):

Strictly speaking, the definitive list of the POSIX functions is the POSIX standards documents themselves.

There's a pretty good introduction to what POSIX is all about, with links to plenty of reference material on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/POSIX).

Answer (score 4):

**zipped versions of the HTML for grepping**

- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/download/
- http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/download/susv4tc2.zip

Those are useful when you start wanting to grep for things, without paying for the PDF.

Mentioned [by Jonathan](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453993/is-there-a-listing-of-the-posix-api-functions/454007?noredirect=1#comment78623115_454007).