# csh error: HOSTTYPE: Undefined variable

Tags: shell, csh

I want to run the pvm2raw utility of [this app](http://code.google.com/p/vvv/downloads/list?q=VIEWER) from the [Volume Library](http://www9.informatik.uni-erlangen.de/External/vollib/).

I get the following error, when typing `csh build.sh tools` on my Ubuntu 10.10 terminal:

[image]

Why is this?

Answer (score 3):

Do you have instructions to launch a `.sh` file with `csh`?

While it is not necessary to name a csh script with `.csh`, `.sh` files usually imply Bourne or bash shell scripts.

Also your scrip name implies a build process. Builds are typically done with the default shell, either Bourne (`sh`) on old unix systems like Solaris, AIX, HP and others, and `bash` for Linux.

**You should be able to just run `build.sh` without any shell preceding it** (unless you have written the script yourself or have been given instructions to do so).

All that Jonathan Leffler says is true. I would add that csh does allow for empty variables with the 'notation' `$?varName` , which can be used like

```
if ( ! $?HOSTNAME ) then
    setenv HOSTNAME `hostname`
endif
```

So, did you write the `build.sh` or are you using a provided script?

If you've written your own csh script, use the block of code to check and provide default values for **all** of your variables. (There are other ways to achieve this, like `source $HOME/.env_file`, where you have to make a `$HOME/.env_file` that lists all of the variable assignments your script needs).

If you're using a provided script, **on Ubuntu** is is highly like that it is really a bash script.  Look at the first line of that script, does it say `#!/bin/bash` (or similar), if yes, confirm script is set to execute, `ls -l build.sh`, you need to see something like `-rwxr-xr-x` at the front of the line, the 'x's being the key bit. If not then `chmod 755 build.sh` will solve that. Once permissions allow execution, just run `./build.sh`.

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 2):

The C Shell doesn't like you to refer to undefined variables.  So, you need to set `$HOSTTYPE` before running the script, or fix the script so that it determines `$HOSTTYPE` correctly for itself.

The Bourne shell and derivatives treat an undefined variable as an empty string most of the time.

Suggestion: don't use the C Shell for programming.  See: [Csh Programming Considered Harmful](http://www.faqs.org/faqs/unix-faq/shell/csh-whynot/).

Answer (score 2):

**`HOSTTYPE` is a non-POSIX Bash extension**

It is documented in `man bash`, and we can confirm that POSIX does not mention it by downloading and grepping: [Is there a listing of the POSIX API / functions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/453993/is-there-a-listing-of-the-posix-api-functions/45832939#45832939)

Therefore, it is not surprising that the variable is not defined in `csh`, which gives an error.

See also: [Detect the OS from a Bash script](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/394230/detect-the-os-from-a-bash-script)

Answer (score 0):

I too faced similar problem.

Try:: **tcsh build.sh**